# Orangepi zero 2w. Debian 12 installed. How to pass a kernel parameter at startup time?

Tags: debian, kernel, cgroups

I try to install Home Assistant on debian 12 installed on orangepi zero 2w micro.

Home Assistant insists on cgroups v1. But  debian 12 supports cgroups v2.
[docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/) said that I can switch  to cgroups v1 :

> To revert the cgroup version to v1, you need to set
> systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0 instead.

So my understanding is that I should pass this command to kernel at startup.
I can run `orangepi-config` command and have access to U-boot envinroment.
But I have no idea how should I modify U-boot env to pass that command to kernel.

Can someone help me? I am lost.

Alexei

Comment: Hi,

I found a solution. The trick is to add extraargs=systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0 to bootenv

Then Home Assistant can be installed w/o any issue.

Thank you anyway.

Alexei

Comment: I am not sure how can I close this request. Should I?